# Queryset object in Django form not iterable

Tags: django, forms, object, django-queryset, iterable

I'm trying to get the form to create the fields based on what exam page the user is on. In the error page, all local variables have the correct value for form and view, but I keep getting `ExamQuestion` object not iterable and an error at line 0 of the template. It also highlights the render() at line 44 in the view as the source of the problem. If I change line 28 from `exam__name=exam_name` to `exam__name="exam_name"`, basically turning the variable into a str, the page runs but no data is passed.

In the error console choice_list shows `querysets` as individual list items as it should for forms.py

How do I make the object ExamQuestion iterable? I've been stumped for a week now. I've written a hundred ways at this point.

I know it's listing questions instead of answers for the questions, I'm just trying to get it to load ANY `queryset` and freaking run at this point.

view

```
def exampage(request, exam_name):

    exams = Exam.objects.all()
    questionlist = ExamQuestion.objects.filter(exam__name=exam_name)
    choicelist = ExamChoice.objects.filter(question__exam__name=exam_name)


    form = ExamTest(request.POST, exam_name=exam_name)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            #form.save()
            #choice = form.cleaned_data.get('choice')
            return redirect('exampage.html')
            return render(request, 'exams/exampage.html', {'exams': exams,'questionlist': questionlist, 'exam_name': exam_name, 'choicelist': choicelist, 'form': form, 'choice': choice})

    else:
        form = ExamTest(exam_name=exam_name)

    return render(request, 'exams/exampage.html', {'exams': exams,'questionlist': questionlist, 'exam_name': exam_name, 'choicelist': choicelist, 'form': form})
```

form

```
class ExamTest(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exam_name = kwargs.pop('exam_name')

        super(ExamTest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #choice_list = [x for x in ExamQuestion.objects.filter(exam__name="dcjs01")]
        #choice_list = []
        x = ExamQuestion.objects.filter(exam__name=exam_name)
        #for q in x:
        #    choice_list.append(q)
        self.fields["choices"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=x,  label="testlabel")
```

template

```
{% extends 'portal/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{{ exam_name }} Page</h1>
{{ exam_id }}
<hr>

{% for exam in exams %}
<li><a href="/exams/{{ exam.name }}/">{{ exam }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

<h1>! {{ questionlist }} !</h1>


    <form method="post" action="#">
      {% csrf_token %}
        formtest{{ form }}
    <button type="submit"> finish test </button>
    </form>




{% endblock %}
```

Comment: From the code you posted "choices=x" looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the question is - you getting the ExamQuestion not iterable error:

- here I think is the problem, that you, in the Form **init** function pass the Queryset (objects.filter(xxx)), but not the .all() which will select it.
- the second thought is - would'n it be better to pass the questions as a parameter to the Form, as you previously selected all the question for this particular exam?

Comment: I kinda get what you're saying but how would i change it? Sorry still new to django EDIT - refering to changing objects.filter(xxx) to .all().

Comment: It would go like: x = ExamQuestion.objects.filter(exam__name=exam_name).all()

Comment: still getting ExamQuestion object not iterable

Comment: objects.filter returns a queryset. Even when there are no records in it, it is still iterable. Adding all() is not requred

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. choices=x needs to be a tuple

```
self.fields['name'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in x]))
```